# Google Maps Android Circle fill not working

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I'm using a `MapView` to display a `Google Map` and the trying to create a circle overlay. But for some reason the circle border is displayed but it is not filled with any color, here is what is generated using the android [emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lCsb.png):

Here is an idea of what I would like to [achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzzjN.png) (i created it through the w3school online editor).

Here is the code:

```
   LatLng center = new LatLng(-16.272425327210556,166.4380745618525);
   double radius = 9944545.500957435;
   CircleOptions co = new CircleOptions().center(center).clickable(false).radius((radius)).fillColor(Color.YELLOW).visible(false);
   this.marker_twilight_civil = map.addCircle(co);
```

I tried with a different radius value and actually it works with a specific one, here i created 3 circles with different radius values, and olny one is filled, the other two are not filled.

Here is the code for the circle that is filled correctly

```
LatLng center = new LatLng(-16.272425356472187,166.43807456511806);
double radius = 8006044.77150472;
CircleOptions co = new CircleOptions().center(center).clickable(false).radius((radius)).fillColor(Color.GREEN).visible(true);
this.marker_night = map.addCircle(co);
```

Could it be a issue with the too large radius? But on the web version is working well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the radius is too large.  Google Maps uses a Mercator projection, which will skew circles if they are large enough.  For technical reasons, if the shape isn't "closed" then the fill won't be applied.  If the shape is too large, or too close to the highly-skewed top or bottom of the map, then the shape will break open and the fill will be ignored.

If it was truly important you could try forcing a custom Projection on Google Maps (which could avoid the skew and keep the shape closed), but this isn't a well-tread path and I can't provide a solution beyond the link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple